Differences between pyenv and repo install for Python versions
If I install Python via pyenv, will there be conflicts if I previosuly used sudo apt-get install python3?
I have used pyenv to get a specific version (3.7.5) to revive an old project running in a Ubuntu 22.04 LTS machine and I am facing issues such that:
"setup.py" install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools. during the build process. My current hypothesis is that pyenv did not installed python well and pip is not catching up with it.
Could you assist me with this issue? Is there another correct method to have multiple versions of python in the ubuntu 22.04 LTS machine?
Note:

pip==22.0.2
setuptools==59.6.0
wheel==0.37.1


If you encounter persistent issues with pyenv, you can try using pyenv's competitor asdf or using Docker/virtual machines for isolation

The issue you're seeing, "setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.", is not related to conflicts betweenpyenvand apt-get install python3. It arises because the use of setup.py install has been deprecated in favor of modern tools like pip and build.

I'm trying to resurrect an old project into a VM machine running Ubuntu 22.04 and needs 3.7.5 version. When running the setup.py is shows that error message. Do you have any hint to solve this issue?

If your project has a requirements.txt, install it  or with Python 3.7.5, you can pair it with older versions of setuptools and pip, which still support the setup.py install workflow
